# Facebook page help: Is it possible to create 2 options for a non-fan visitor

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

Here's the scenario. We have this Promo, and this promo has the official website outside facebook. When a visitor sign-up on our promo or just visited the official promo website and click the link from this official website and go the facebook page. On facebook page if visitor is not yet fan of the page, we have this creative work and has this message to "LIKE" the button by clicking the like button above the fb page. And after clicking the "LIKE" button on that same tab there will be a creative work also that says "Thank you... blah blah".

But if this visitor is not came from the Official promo page, and he/she just browse it directly via referrals like coming from email campaign. the default landing page is different above with thank you messages. Same visitor and not yet a fan, after clicking the "LIKE" button the next creative work will be something like ads that says "we have this promo blah blah and a clickable button that goes to the official promo page.

I don't think if its clear. But I just need to know if this is possible to have this 2 options on a non-fan of our page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I will do is go to a page, set the session based on the querystring. Then redirect to the FB page. Then, the page on the FB iframe will be able to determine what to be shown. Hope it clears.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you have link for this? I mean a DOCs or something like that.

Comment: Not really. But you can't just use javascript to archieve this. You need some server processing (ie. .Net/Ruby)

Comment: do you know any website that has this kind of flow? when visitors browse their facebook page and they come from the external landing page and clicking the like button on fb page is different message when they come directly in their facebook page?

Comment: Not exactly the same. Try http://www.facebook.com/nissanmicraaus/?sk=app_250097565036152 app. You can go directly to the app or go through the sopt link which will be handled differently. It's done using the app_data query string.